# Hide JSON file from public; only access for my Android app

Tags: android, json

I want to hide my JSON file from the public. So that noone can download this JSON data or go through the browser in my JSON file.
I want only that my own developed app can get the information of this JSON file.

Is there a way to code this? Thanks for answering.

Comment: you have to create a process that would identify your app explicitly. it's not 100% safe but better than nothing

Comment: Must I do this in my JSON file? Can you show me how I code this and which aspects can identify my app?

Comment: where is the json stored?

Comment: The json is stored in my webspace, it's a file under my domain

Comment: You can try to use authentication with the web server, or make prossess of authentication in your webspace with server-side code. you'll have to send your identification, either in plain text (not recommended) or in some encrypted data that only you could decrypt

Comment: Can you show me in an answer maybe with a code how you mean this? Thanks

Comment: there are a lot of ways to do it, depending on the server side technologies. there is not one answer

Comment: you can check some conditions on your server-side before replying with the JSON, like some secret key, which will be sent only from your app.

Comment: Can you show me how to code this please? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to use token which is only known to your server and your client (mobile app) while making call to your server to get the json data. checkout the following tutorial on how to fetch data from server using token.

[android token authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)

---

[retrofit token authentication](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android)

```java
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://yourbackend.example.com/tokensignin");

try {
    List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idToken", idToken));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    final String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Log.i(TAG, "Signed in as: " + responseBody);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error sending ID token to backend.", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error sending ID token to backend.", e);
}
```

Or add a token to retrofit NetworkInterceptor

```java
 builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
              @Override
              public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                  request.addHeader("Authorization", authToken);
              }
          });
      }
```

Comment: Please describe the steps in your answer with any relevant quotes from your link.  This way, if the link breaks your answer is still useful.  Check out [answer]